# Performance of SKSpriteNode's 'color' & 'colorBlendFactor' properties

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit app with a confetti effect created via `SKSpriteNode`. Each piece of confetti is a node.

My current strategy is the following:

1. Initialize the node with a white square image, like this: `SKSpriteNode(texture: whiteSquareImage)`.
2. Set the node's `color` property to a non-white color, like this: `node.color = UIColor.green`.
3. Set the node's `colorBlendFactor` property, like this: `node.colorBlendFactor = 1.0`.

**Question:** Is there a performance penalty for having the system color the sprite, as opposed to simply using *colored* images?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an interesting question! Almost by policy, I always use white-color assets for any sprite in my apps that are single-color. This allows me to be extra-dynamic with my colors, since they can be managed in code or scene files. I have multiple nicely successful apps in the App Store with this methodology in place and I have never seen any issues or performance penalty in using *color* and *colorBlendFactor*. So, my first instinct is to answer: don't worry about it :).

Of course, you could test it out by overloading the simulator with so much confetti that it starts to run out of performance, and then measuring the difference, but I think you'll be fine. iPhones and iPads are so performant these days that it takes quite a lot to make a dent. I would bet that you don't see any difference anyway.